# How to check if there is a line segment between two given points?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, deep-learning, object-detection

I made a model that predicts electrical symbols and junctions:
[image of model inference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXdm5.png).

Given the *xywh* coordinates of each junctions' bounding box in a form of a dataframe: [image of the dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HS2nk.png), how would I make an output that stores the location of all the wires in a .txt file in a form of: (x<sub>start</sub>,y<sub>start</sub>), (x<sub>end</sub>,y<sub>end</sub>).

I'm stuck at writing a way to check if there is a valid line (wire) between any two given junctions.

```
data = df.loc[df['name'] == 'junction']

# iterates through all of the junctions
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    for index2, row2 in data.iterrows():
        check_if_wire_is_valid()
```

My attempt was to erase all electrical symbols (make everything in bounding boxes white except for junctions) from the inference image and run cv.HoughLinesP to find wires. How can I write a function that checks if the cv.HoughLinesP output lies between two junctions?

Note that the minimum distance that lies between two junctions should be greater than 1px because if I have a [parallel circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FM27L.png) like such: top left and bottom right junction would "detect" more than 1px of line between them and misinterpret that as a valid line.

**EDIT**: [minAreaRect on contours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hTgF.png) . I've drawn this circuit with no elements for simplification and testing. This is the resulting minAreaRect found for the given contours. I can't seem to find a way to properly validate lines from this.

My initial solution was to compare any two junctions and if they are relatively close on the *x*-axis, then I would say that those two junctions form a vertical wire, and if other two junctions were close on the *y*-axis I would conclude they form a horizontal wire. [junction distance to axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWvbu.jpg).

Now, this would create a problem if I had a diagonal line. I'm trying find a solution that is consistent and applicable to every circuit. I believe I'm onto something with HoughLinesP method or contours but that's as far as my knowledge can assist me.

The main goal is to create an LTSpice readable circuit for simulating purposes. Should I change my method of finding valid lines? If so, what is your take on the problem?

Comment: image recognition....  need `cv2` for that.

Answer (score 0):

This should be doable using `findContours()`. A wire is always a (roughly) straigt line, right ?

- Paint the classified boxes white, as you said
- `threshold()` to get a binary image with the wires (and other symbols and letters) in **white**, everything else black.
- run `findContours()` on that to extract objects.
- Get the bounding boxes (`minAreaRect`) for all contours
- discard all contours with a too wide side ratio, those are letter or symbols, keep only those slim enough to be a wire

Now you got all wires as objects, similiar to the junction list. Now, for how to merge those two... Some options that come to mind:

- Grow the boxes by a certain amount, and check if they overlap.
- Interpolate a line from the wire boxes and check if they cross any intersection box close by.
- Or the other way around: draw a line between intersections and check how much of it goes through a certain wire box.

This is a pure math problem, and i don't know what you performance requirements are. So i'll leave it at that.